# Need Google App Script to Generate Fusion Table Views

Tags: google-fusion-tables

Is it possible to use Google App Script to create fusion table views (from an existing FT) and, optionally with filter settings?  I need to enumerate the columns of the FT (which I know how to do) and create different views and ideally, I need to get their URLs too.  I have not seen any documentation or examples that discuss this.

Comment: removed apps script tag since the o.p. self answered a non apps script answer.

Comment: how is this a non-script question?  It is precisely that!!

Comment: sorry somehow missed this. if this is not in advanced services (used to be) see if its part of the rest ft api.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found the docs that show how to do this.  See: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference#createView